# Can't create a symmetric link graph using Gojs

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have been trying to use GoJS to draw some interactive graphs in my application but I couldn't figure out how to make a link graph to display symmetrically.
The current graph that I drew looked like this image.

[image: Current display]

In the image, I expect the element `A>90` to be symmetric with the `A>91` element but I can't make it happen.
Can anyone give me a hint to correctly config GoJS to achieve this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric"?  It appears to me that the "A>*" nodes are evenly spaced vertically.  I suggest providing a screenshot or sketch showing what you want,  and describing how you got this diagram.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods I think they mean that the upper and lower halves of the diagram should be mirrored with the connectors from the lower (+) nodes exiting upwards